# How to allow back button to properly reverse transition animation between fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am attempting to add a simple slide animation between fragments in fragment container within an Activity. My code runs on a test device running Android Oreo.

### Here is my code:

In **MyActivity's** `onCreate()`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, oldFragment, OldFragment.class.getName())
      .commit();
}
```

In code for a **Button's** `onClick()`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left,
        R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, NewFragment.class.getName())
    .addToBackStack(NewFragment.class.getName())
    .commit();
```

**res\anim\enter_from_left.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

**res\anim\enter_from_right.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

**res\anim\exit_to_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

**res\anim\exit_to_right.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

Please note that my `fragment` classes extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `MyActivity`extends `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`.

### My problem:

Animating from OldFragment to NewFragment works fine. NewFragment slides in from the right. However, when I press the back button, no animation occurs - it just "jumps" to OldFragment.

### Question:

Where have I made a mistake? How can I get the animation from NewFragment to OldFragment working when the back button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, when you replace the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left,R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, NewFragment.class.getName()).addToBackStack(NewFragment.class.getName()).commit();
```

> On back press you have to remove fragment or pop backstage. When you remove fragment or pop backstage the no need to set animation it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the response! How does this differ from my code? Also, `On back press you have to remove fragment or pop backstage` <- what do you mean - I was hoping that the Activity's onBackPressed would handle this automatically.